# php filemtime in a loop at CLI on Windows doesn't get updates

Tags: php, loops, command-line-interface, filemtime

I have a loop

```
while (true) {
    $time = filemtime($file);
    echo date("Y m d H i s", $time) . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(3);
}
```

Then I change the file, and PHP doesn't see modification unless I restart the loop. After restart, PHP shows new mod date. How can I overcome this?

Comment: See note #2: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php#refsect1-function.filemtime-notes

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearstatcache()` to clear chached vale for that file.